# "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable"

Tags: java

I get an error saying "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable" where is says else (itemNumber >=15)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ch3Asg
{

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        // Variables
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int itemNumber = 0;
            double shippingCost = 0;

        // Items Purchased
            System.out.println("How many items did you purchase? ");
            itemNumber = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

        // One Item Purchased
            if ( itemNumber == 1 )
            {
                shippingCost = 2.99;
            }   

        // 2-5 Items Purchased
            else if ( itemNumber >= 2 && itemNumber <= 5 );
            {
                shippingCost = 2.99 + 1.99 * (itemNumber - 1);
            }

        // 5-15 Items Purchased
            if ( itemNumber > 5 && itemNumber < 15)
            {
                shippingCost = 2.99 + 1.99 * (itemNumber - 1) + 1.49 * (itemNumber - 5);
            }
        // More Than 15 Items Purchased
            else ( itemNumber >= 15 )
            {
                shippingCost = 2.99 + 1.99 * (itemNumber - 1) + 1.49 * (itemNumber - 5)
                        + .99 * (itemNumber - 14);
            }
        // Display Cost
            System.out.printf("Shipping Cost is: $%.2f", shippingCost);
    }

}
```

Comment: you dont need to tell java what else could be the case. it believes you.

Comment: `else ( itemNumber >= 15 )` is nonsense.  The poor compiler's doing the best it can to understand it.

Comment: You can remove the semicolon from the `else if` block that your did already properly code (2-5 Items Purchased).  You'll want the 5-15 Items Purchased case to be an `else if`, to be consistent with the cases around it.

Answer (score 6):

`else (boolean statement)` is meaningless. I think that you forgot the if:

```
else ( itemNumber >= 15 )
```

should be

```
else if ( itemNumber >= 15 )
```

Or else if it represents the last and default option, it could be simply:

```
else {
   //..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`else` construct does not take an expression, so

```
    else ( itemNumber >= 15 )
```

is syntactically wrong.

You need to use `else if` instead

```
    else if ( itemNumber >= 15 )
```